# Error when try installing budspencer theme for fish shell

Tags: shell, fish

**My fish conf (.config/fish/config.fish)**

```
set -e fish_key_bindings
set -U fish_key_bindings fish_vi_key_bindings
set fish_path $HOME/.oh-my-fish
set fish_theme budspencer
. $fish_path/oh-my-fish.fish
```

result in error: https://gist.github.com/LuizCarvalho/925de989c306828a410a

if I remove theme and sets result in:

```
  desenvolvimento@dp-inf015:~$ fish
  Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
  Type help for instructions on how to use fish
  fish: Unknown command “fish_vi_key_bindings”
  Standard input: begin; fish_vi_key_bindings ;end 
                         ^
  in . (source) call of file “-”, 
    called on standard input,

  in function “__fish_reload_key_bindings”,
    called on line 209 of file “/usr/share/fish/functions/__fish_config_interactive.fish”,

  in function “__fish_config_interactive”,
    called on line 108 of file “/usr/share/fish/config.fish”,

  in function “__fish_on_interactive”,
    called on standard input,

  in event handler: handler for generic event “fish_prompt”
```

If I uninstall fish, oh-my-fish and all file conf and install again, error keeps happening...
How I can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vi bindings are in an upcoming release, but not yet in a public one. That is why you get the error.

If you want to get vi bindings working and are willing to live on the edge, you can install the latest fish from trunk. If you are using homebrew, run `brew install fish --HEAD`. Or if you prefer to do it the old fashioned way, there's [build instructions here](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell#autotools-build).

Alternatively, if you understandably prefer to remain on the most recent public release, you should delete the `fish_vi_key_bindings` lines from config.fish.

Comment: Thanks! Work fine with compile repository git clone git://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell.git
:D